# Load Image From Dyamic Folders In PHP

Tags: php

I wonder whether may possibly be able to help me please.

I'm trying to build a php script that loads an image from a folder called 'Thumbnails':

The php code below is an extract from my script which loads the image.

```
<?php 

  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($galleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
```

From information I've read, and guidance I've received from this site, I've been using 'realpath' to get the full path of the folder, which is:

`/homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/Thumbnails`

Normally I could use this to point the script to open the desired image but the problem I have is that two of the folders, 'username' and 'location' are created dynamically and the va;ues change for each user and location, in the above these are values 'IRHM73' (username) and '1' (location).

I've been trying for days now to find a way to point the script so that it opens the correct filepath irrespective of the value, and I just can't seem to find the solution. In addition to this, I also need to retrieve only those images pertient to the current user and location.

I've tried the following:

```
<?php 

  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $usernamefolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $locationfolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $thumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
```

But the images fail to load and I'm now at a loss about how to solve this.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks and regards

Comment: How can you say that the image fails to load?

Comment: "Fail to load"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the misunderstanding. I'll clarify. My gallery page loads, but there are no images shown. I also want to apologise because some of the code was missing from my original post. I've now added this. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see you use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for the $absGalleryPath var. But you've falied to notice that you've used '/' in $galleryPath ("UploadedFiles/") and 'Thumbnails/', defeating the purpose of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. If '/' works, then maybe you should change DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to '/'. Might work.

Comment: Hi @siideesh, many thanks for this. Firstly apologies as I missed some of the code from my original post, I've now added this. Could I just check though that the `absGalleryPath` should be:  `$absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath)/  $username/  $location/ ;` Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM very sorry for the late reply, erm `$absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . "/" . $username . "/" $location . "/";`

Comment: You might also want to double check if you have set this variable **after** the dynamic directories (eg IRHM73/1/) have been created, to be on the safe side

Comment: Hi @siidheesh, it's no problem at all. I appreciate the help. I've just tried to run your suggested code and unfortunately I receive the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/gallery.php on line 9` I am pretty new to PHP, you may have guessed. Line 9 is the code I've just inserted. Could you perhaps tell me please what the error may mean? Kind regards

Comment: what exactly is the line you inserted? also, create a test.php in your current script folder and run `echo getcwd();` to see your current working directory, maybe you dont have to use an absolute real path

Comment: Hi this is the line:`$absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . "/" . $username . "/" $location . "/";` I've also run the script you suggested, and the path is as follows:`/homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1` I think the issue is that fact that I need to get the script o look for the variables rather than the 'IRHM73 - username value' and '1 - location value' and it's this bit I'm really struggling with. Regards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10057/discussion-between-siidheesh-and-irhm)